# load values from a dataset to array

Tags: sas

I have an dataset with 150 rows and 1 column,that looks like;

```
surv_probs
0.15
0.12
0.10
0.9
```

I am getting an error message when I use the function scan to load the values into an array in a datastep. The field surv_probs are text/characters. The problem is that sas tries to convert the probabilites to numeric values then the scan function does'nt work. the log says: "scan function has to many arguments". Could someone maybe help me to resolve this problem for me.

```
proc sql;
select surv_probs
into: probs_lst separated by ','
from mydataset;
quit;


data test;
j=1;
array probs_arr{150};
do while(scan(&probs_lst,j,',') ne '');
probs_arr{j} = scan(&probs_lst,j,',');
j = j+1;
end;
run;
```

Comment: Why would you transfer numbers to strings and back to numbers?  Why not just leave them as numbers and skip the macro variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SAS code string literals need to have quotes around them.

```
do while(scan("&probs_lst",j,',') ne '');
probs_arr{j} = scan("&probs_lst",j,',');
```

But don't do that. Leave the data as numbers and avoid the loss of precision that will happen by transferring them to text and back again.

```
proc transpose data=mydataset out=test(drop=_name_) prefix=probs_arr ;
  var surv_probs;
run;
```